# Loop through key value pair

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I loop through a key value pair array?

I declare mine as such:

```
produse!: {[key: string] : ProductDTO}[];
```

Then I loop through it like so:

```
for (let produs of this.produse) {
  category.produse.push((produs as ProductDTO).toSerialized());
}
```

But I get this error:

> Conversion of type '{ [key: string]: ProductDTO; }' to type 'ProductDTO' may be a mistake

I also tried this:

```
for (let produs of Object.values(this.produse))
```

with the same effect.

Comment: Your `produse` is an array and not an object because you added `[]` to the end of it

Comment: That would make sense as to why the second one does not work, but shouldn't the firs one loop trough only the value?

Comment: The "value" in this case is of type `{[key: string] : ProductDTO}` and the error message is quite explicit in saying that you're trying to add an object of the aforementioned type to an array of `ProductDTO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.produse` is an array of objects (`Array<{[key: string] : ProductDTO}>`). At the end of type `[]` means that it is an array. So you need to loop array first, then objects:

```
for (const produses of this.produse) {
  for (const produs of Object.values(produses) {
    category.produse.push(produs.toSerialized());
  }
}
```

You can also rewrite that using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```
const serialized = this.produse.flatMap(
  produses => Object.values(produses).map(v => v.toSerialized())
);

// Rewrite category.produse
category.produse = serialized;

// Or append new products and keep older
category.produse.push(...serialized);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following syntax proved to work but it is not as elegant as I would want.

```
 for(let produs of this.produse){
      category.produse.push((Object.values(produs)[0] as ProductDTO).toSerialized())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging purely by the types provided, you'll need two loops:

```
for (const produsMap of this.produse) {            // produsMap is of type {[key: string] : ProductDTO}
  const produsList = Object.values(produsMap);     // produsList is of type ProductDTO[]
  for (const produs of produsList) {               // produs is of type ProductDTO
    category.produse.push(produs.toSerialized());
  }
}
```